# R append function

Tags: r, append

I'm writing an R script that parses out the a state abbreviation from a column in a `data.frame`. It then uses the `which()` function to determine the index of the found state abbreviation in a look up data frame that contains state abbreviations and their corresponding full state names. I then use the found index to access the the full state name and append it to a vector called `completeList`. I then add the vector `completeList` which should contain the full state names to my original data frame under a newly created column `STATE_NAME`.

However, for some reason `completeList` only contains the indexes that were found earlier and not the full state names that I expected. What did I do wrong?

```
#read in csv weather data file 
file <- read.csv(header = TRUE, file = "C:\\Users\\michael.guarino1\\Desktop\\Work\\weather\\nov_2_1976\\734677_cleaned.csv")
#read in csv state Abbreviation file
abbreviationsFile<-read.csv(header=TRUE, file="C:\\Users\\michael.guarino1\\Desktop\\Work\\weather\\stateAbbreviationMatches.csv")
#iterate through STATION_NAME and store abreviations
completeList<-c()
for(stateAbvr in file$STATION_NAME){
     addTo<-(substring(stateAbvr,(nchar(stateAbvr)-4),(nchar(stateAbvr)-3)))
     index<-which(abbreviationsFile$Abbreviation==addTo)
     addCompleteStateName<-(abbreviationsFile[index,1])
     completeList<-append(completeList, addCompleteStateName)
}
file["STATE_NAME"]<-completeList

>completeList
[1] 27 17 17 29 42 50 20 53 45 19 22 52  9 29 26 37  8 58 35
```

Here is the csv file where the abbreviation of the station is found

```
STATION STATION_NAME    ELEVATION
GHCND:USC00202381   EAST JORDAN MI US   180.1
GHCND:USC00111290   CARLYLE RESERVOIR IL US 153
GHCND:USC00116661   PAW PAW 2 S IL US   274.9
GHCND:USC00228556   SUMRALL MS US   88.1
GHCND:USC00340292   ARDMORE OK US   267.9
GHCND:USC00408522   SPARTA WASTEWATER PLANT TN US   289.9
GHCND:USC00148341   VALLEY FALLS KS US  283.5
GHCND:USW00014742   BURLINGTON INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT VT US  101.2
GHCND:USC00367782   SALINA 3 W PA US    338
GHCND:USC00134142   IOWA FALLS IA US    356.9
GHCND:USC00161565   CARVILLE 2 SW LA US 9.1
GHCND:USC00421446   CITY CRK WATER PLANT UT US  1628.9
GHCND:USW00013781   WILMINGTON NEW CASTLE CO AIRPORT DE US  22.6
GHCND:USC00229400   WATER VALLEY MS US  116.1
GHCND:USC00190562   BELCHERTOWN MA US   171
GHCND:USW00094728   NEW YORK CENTRAL PARK OBS BELVEDERE TOWER NY US 40.2
GHCND:USC00060973   BURLINGTON CT US    155.4
GHCND:USC00475516   MINOCQUA WI US  484.9
GHCND:USC00286055   NEW BRUNSWICK 3 SE NJ US    38.1
```

Here is the csv file where we look up abbreviations and find the corresponding full state name

```
State/Possession    Abbreviation
Alabama AL
Alaska  AK
American Samoa  AS
Arizona AZ
Arkansas    AR
California  CA
Colorado    CO
Connecticut CT
Delaware    DE
District of Columbia    DC
Federated States of Micronesia  FM
Florida FL
Georgia GA
Guam    GU
Hawaii  HI
Idaho   ID
Illinois    IL
Indiana IN
Iowa    IA
Kansas  KS
Kentucky    KY
Louisiana   LA
Maine   ME
Marshall Islands    MH
Maryland    MD
Massachusetts   MA
Michigan    MI
Minnesota   MN
Mississippi MS
Missouri    MO
Montana MT
Nebraska    NE
Nevada  NV
New Hampshire   NH
New Jersey  NJ
New Mexico  NM
New York    NY
North Carolina  NC
North Dakota    ND
Northern Mariana Islands    MP
Ohio    OH
Oklahoma    OK
Oregon  OR
Palau   PW
Pennsylvania    PA
Puerto Rico PR
Rhode Island    RI
South Carolina  SC
South Dakota    SD
Tennessee   TN
Texas   TX
Utah    UT
Vermont VT
Virgin Islands  VI
Virginia    VA
Washington  WA
West Virginia   WV
Wisconsin   WI
Wyoming WY
```

Why am I not getting the full state name?

Comment: I pulled it from excel, please pardon the fact that there are no commas; however, the format is csv

Answer (score 1):

figured it out

```
#read in csv weather data file 
file <- read.csv(header = TRUE, file = "C:\\Users\\michael.guarino1\\Desktop\\Work\\weather\\nov_2_1976\\734677_cleaned.csv")
#read in csv state Abbreviation file
abbreviationsFile<-read.csv(header=TRUE, file="C:\\Users\\michael.guarino1\\Desktop\\Work\\weather\\stateAbbreviationMatches.csv")
#iterate through STATION_NAME and store abreviations
completeList<-c()
for(stateAbvr in file$STATION_NAME){
  addTo<-(substring(stateAbvr,(nchar(stateAbvr)-4),(nchar(stateAbvr)-3)))
  index<-which(abbreviationsFile$Abbreviation==addTo)
  addCompleteStateName<-(abbreviationsFile[index,1])
  completeList<-append(completeList, toString(addCompleteStateName))
}
file["STATE_NAME"]<-completeList
```

the type was being forced to an integer

Comment: Another method is to use the "stringsAsFactors =FALSE"  option in the read.csv function.  By default strings are converted to factors with the read statements.

Answer (score 0):

The variable addCompleteStateName is a factor. You can convert it to a character to append the labels.

```
#iterate through STATION_NAME and store abreviations
completeList<-c()

for(stateAbvr in file$STATION_NAME){

  addTo<-(substring(stateAbvr,(nchar(stateAbvr)-4),(nchar(stateAbvr)-3)))

  index<-which(abbreviationsFile$Abbreviation==addTo)

  addCompleteStateName<-(abbreviationsFile[index,1])

  # modified to convert addCompleteStateName to character
  completeList<-append(completeList, as.character(addCompleteStateName))

}

file["STATE_NAME"]<-completeList
```

Comment: Looks like I wasn't fast enough. Good on you @MichaelGuarino for finding your own solution.